# Only output matching regex pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that contains 10,000s of rows.  Each row has 8 columns.  One of those columns contains text similar to this:

```
this is a row:   http://somedomain.com | some_text | http://someanotherdomain.com | some_more_text
this is a row:   http://yetanotherdomain.net
this is a row:   https://hereisadomain.org | some_text
```

I'm currently accessing the data in this column this way:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    the_url = row[3]

    # this regex is used to find the hrefs
    href_regex = re.findall('(?:http|ftp)s?://.*', the_url)
    for link in href_regex:
         print (link)
```

Output from the print statement:

```
http://somedomain.com | some_text | http://someanotherdomain.com | some_more_text
http://yetanotherdomain.net
https://hereisadomain.org | some_text
```

How do I obtain only the URLs?

```
http://somedomain.com
http://someanotherdomain.com 
http://yetanotherdomain.net
https://hereisadomain.org
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your pattern to:

```
\b(?:http|ftp)s?://\S+
```

Instead of matching anything with `.*`, match any non-whitespace characters instead with `\S+`. You might want to add a word boundary before your non capturing group, too.

Check it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/34sxdi/3).

Comment: I tried to accept the answer right-way, but I was promoted to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of repeating any character at the end

```
'(?:http|ftp)s?://.*'
                  ^
```

repeat any character *except a space*, to ensure that the pattern will stop matching at the end of a URL:

```
'(?:http|ftp)s?://[^ ]*'
                  ^^^^
```

Comment: Actually this is not correct, you are only negating whitespace and not new lines. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/34sxdi/4). Plus a word boundary would be nice, too.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness OP's code has text before each URL - if that was a problem, he would have seen his `http://yetanotherdomain.net` mashed together with his `https://hereisadomain.org`. I'm doubtful about a word boundary, because URLs can contain trailing non-word characters that are still an important part of the URL